# build regex match pattern for GitHub branches

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm fairly new to bash scripting and regex, but I'm trying to learn. So far, I've gotten this:

```
regexBranchPattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]+"

while [[ ! $branch_name =~ $regexBranchPattern ]]; do
    echo "Specify a branch name"
    read -r branch_name
    if [[ ! $branch_name =~ $regexBranchPattern ]]; then
      echo "Branch name can only conatin letters, numbers, and \"_\"."
    fi
done
```

This is close, but not quite what I want. I want to be able to accept all letters, numbers, "_" and "-" but reject everything else.

EDIT: here is specifically what I'm looking to allow:
- can contain numerical values, but begin with numeric
- must contain characters
- can only contain special characters of "_" and "-" but can not start with either

here are some examples of invalid branch names:

```
4idu
testing/here
-branch_name
```

here are some examples of valid branch names:

```
test-feature
feature_test
feature1-test
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So .. if you want to accept `-`, why not include it in your bracket expression, like `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+`? Also, do you have any restrictions, for example, that a branch name *must* begin with a letter? If so, include some examples of valid and invalid branch names in your question, and show us what you think a regular expression that matches the right (or wrong) ones would look like. Note that at the moment, `_` is a valid branch name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will update my question with more examples and more details about what I'm looking to accomplish

Comment: From your examples, it looks like valid branch names might be *one or more alphanumeric words beginning with a letter, with words separated by hyphens or underscores*. (Is `foo-1` valid?) If this definition works, you can build a regular expression that correctly matches. Give it a shot and we'll all p̶o̶k̶e̶ ̶h̶o̶l̶e̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ suggest improvements. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very clear on your requirements but from what I gather this should cover them all:

```
^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]+$
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/M4ULDF/1)

Explanation:

- `^` - start matching from the beginning
- `[[:alpha:]]` - match one of `A-Z,a-z`
- `[[:alnum:]_-]+` - match at least one of `A-Z,a-z,0-9,_,-`
- `$` - end at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully a GitHub branch is a git branch!:

```
git branch | sed 's/^[* ] //' | egrep '^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*[A-Za-z0-9]$'
```